# How can i set the action on element using that xpath?

Tags: typescript, xpath, automation, mocha.js, appium

Here is xpath of create account button:

```
//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc="ScreenLogin"]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[5]/android.widget.TextView
```

And I want to set action that click on create account button.

Comment: This happen in react-native application

Comment: The question is not clear . Please state what you have done , the screen shot of xml what is your main objective as "click on create account button" is not clear.

The guidelines are in 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
androidDriver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc="ScreenLogin"]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[5]").click();
```

Note: you can't `click()` on `TextView` widget element, you will get an exception by appium. I believe you could shorten this xpath removing unnecessary tree elements.